# Override cropVariants for page media field only

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I have set some cropvariants in my page.typoscript file using
`TCEFORM.sys_file_reference.crop.config.cropVariants`

Works just fine. Now I would like to override these variants for the page "media" field because no cropVariants are needed here. I found the option to override the TCA for certain CTypes (tried this and it works):

`$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['textmedia']['columnsOverrides']['assets']['config']['overrideChildTca']['columns']['crop']['config']`

I am trying to make this work for the pages TCA. I tried

`$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columnsOverrides']['media']['config']['overrideChildTca']['columns']['crop']['config']`

as well as (shot in the dark)

`$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['media']['config']['columns']['crop']['config']`

Any ideas? Bonus points for a typoscript only solution that doesnt require a TCA override in a php file. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columns']['media']['config']['overrideChildTca']['columns']['crop']['config']
```

Comment: I completely missed the "columns" browsing the TCA - my bad. Thanks!